# Trigger as soon as the User intervenes my application?

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, winforms, events

I am already using the following events together in order to understand if the User intervenes my application.

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    static int x, y;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    //If User uses the mouse
    private void Window_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        x = (x + 1);
        if ((x == 1))
        {
            //Do something;
        }
    }

    //If User uses the keyboard
    private void Window_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        y = (y + 1);
        if ((y == 1))
        {
            //Do something;
        }
    }
}
}
```

I dont want to use two code blocks which are **mouse event** and **keyboard event**.

So do you know any alternative code which triggers as soon as the User intervenes my application.

Comment: Write your code in a single method, then call it from the mouse and keyboard events

Comment: Add code after : InitializeComponent();

Comment: What do you define as intervening? Clicks and Keydowns, or even simple mouse movements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use **InputManager.Current.PreProcessInput** event . This is commonly used for log in logoff checking this can be ticked to use in this scenario. One simple sample bellow

```
        protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnStartup(e);
            InputManager.Current.PreProcessInput += new PreProcessInputEventHandler(Current_PreProcessInput);
        }

        private void Current_PreProcessInput(object sender, PreProcessInputEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.StagingItem.Input is MouseEventArgs
                    || e.StagingItem.Input is KeyboardEventArgs
                    || e.StagingItem.Input is TextCompositionEventArgs
                    )
            {
                if (e.StagingItem.Input is MouseEventArgs)
                {
                    MouseEventArgs mouseEventArgs = (MouseEventArgs)e.StagingItem.Input;

                    // no button is pressed and the position is still the same as the application became inactive
                    if (mouseEventArgs.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Released &&
                        mouseEventArgs.RightButton == MouseButtonState.Released &&
                        mouseEventArgs.MiddleButton == MouseButtonState.Released &&
                        mouseEventArgs.XButton1 == MouseButtonState.Released )
                        return;
                }

                // User activity log for testing
                Debug.WriteLine("Got the event :" + e.StagingItem.Input.ToString());
            }
        }
```